# Why does the dynamic linker try to open a file that it knows doesn't exist?

Tags: linker, ld, dynamic-linking, stat

If I try to link to an unknown library (`-lunknown`) and have a look (using strace) to see what the linker is doing, I noticed that, immediately after a `stat` returns -1 (`ENOENT`), the linker tries to `open` the file that it has just discovered doesn't exist. From the strace output, we see:

```
stat("/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libunknown.so", 0x7fff6694df50) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libunknown.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libunknown.a", 0x7fff6694dfb0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/libunknown.a", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
... [lots of similar lines here]
```

ld version:

```
$ ld -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.23.2
```

Why would the linker bother trying `open` after `stat` returned -1?

Comment: My version of ld doesn't do that, I only have open() calls, no stat() calls. To figure out why it does it for you, use GDB and try putting a breakpoint in open() and look at the backtrace and the caller to see why it gets called.